# Assistance adding HTML form field to existing form when a button is pressed without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling to find a solution to the below. I have a HTML page with a form that a user can enter information on. There are 8 variables to enter, Once the user clicks submit on the form I want JQuery/JavaScript to create a dynamic table entry to populate the page with the information provided.

I have the table snippet I think I would use but I don't know where to start with the JS/JQ with having so many variables. Any pointers in the right direction would help

HMTL Form Data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Team Sheet</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Show Popup Form</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
      <form method="post" action="/action_page_post.php">
        <div>
          <h3>Team Entry</h3>
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable1:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable1">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable2:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable2">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable3:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable3">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable4:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable4">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable5:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable5">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable6:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable6">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable7:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable7">
          <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable8:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Variable8">
          <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Get Calling!</h1>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamic HTML Table Snippet:

```
<tr>
<td>Variable1</td>
<td>Variable2</td>
<td>Variable3</td>
<td><a href="Variable4" target="_blank" target="_blank" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable5</a></td>
<td><a href="mailto:Variable6" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable6</a></td>
<td><a href="mailto:Variable7" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Variable7</a></td>
<td>Variable8</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: so basically you want to populate an existing table OR create a new table and populate it ?

Answer (score 0):

In a html page, repeated IDs are to be avoided, which is quite obvious. Following this principle, you will find quite easy to handle what you call multiple variables.

Anyway, if I understood you well, relying on the snippet you provided:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var html_table_string = '<tr>';
  $("form input[type=text]").each(function () {
    html_table_string += '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
  });
  html_table_string += '</tr>';

  $("table").append(html_table_string);

});
```

put the code above in a script tag and add a table structure anywhere in your page

This piece of code will fill the table with the data that the user has entered in the form, on submit click. It's quite general, but it might be a good starting point. Note that the **event.preventDefault()** block the default execution of the form's submit, so if you intend to store the data, you will need a sort of asynchronous logic to do that for you.

To clarify, I apologize for the obviousness, to save the data you will need a database

Answer (score 0):

So wherever you want this table in your html, put an empty table tag with a unique ID. You also only ever want your elements to have UNIQUE IDs, so I changed them to be usrnm1, usrnm2, etc. :) This is especially important when using JS/JQuery, as you can use the "getElementById" function to grab any element's info! In this case, you get your variables by grabbing info from each text box. If you want the table to add lines each time the user submits, then keep the function as "$("#myTable").append(...". Otherwise, change it to "$("#myTable").html(...". That will replace everything that is in the table with the new information every time.

```js
function submitUserForm() { 
  var user1 = $("#usrnm1").val();
  var user2 = $("#usrnm2").val();
  var user3 = $("#usrnm3").val();
  var user4 = $("#usrnm4").val();
  var user5 = $("#usrnm5").val();
  var user6 = $("#usrnm6").val();
  var user7 = $("#usrnm7").val();
  var user8 = $("#usrnm8").val();
  $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + user1 + "</td><td>" + user2 + "</td><td>" + user3 + "</td><td><a href='" + user4 + "'     target='_blank' target='_blank' class='external-link' rel='nofollow'>" + user5 + "</a></td><td><a href='mailto:" + user6 + "' class='external-link' rel='nofollow'>" + user6 + "</a></td><td><a href='mailto:" + user7 + "' class='external-link' rel='nofollow'>" + user7 + "</a></td><td>" + user8 + "</td></tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h3>Team Entry</h3>
<form method="post" onsubmit="submitUserForm(); return false;">
          
          <label for="usrnm1" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable1:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm1" placeholder="Variable1">
          <label for="usrnm2" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable2:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm2" placeholder="Variable2">
          <label for="usrnm3" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable3:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm3" placeholder="Variable3">
          <label for="usrnm4" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable4:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm4" placeholder="Variable4">
          <label for="usrnm5" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable5:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm5" placeholder="Variable5">
          <label for="usrnm6" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable6:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm6" placeholder="Variable6">
          <label for="usrnm7" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable7:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm7" placeholder="Variable7">
          <label for="usrnm8" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Variable8:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm8" placeholder="Variable8">
          <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
      </form>

<table id="myTable"></table>
```